# New chat rooms are open - how to encourage more people to participate in conversations?

Tags: discussion, chat

It took a little bit of time but I finally managed to make my way to the new chatrooms that have been made available to the StackExchange community.

Unfortunately there were not many chatrooms open, so I took it upon myself to create one for Professional Development / Mentorship, which I believe is something that at least according to my colleagues is something that people at all different levels in their career should be looking to do more of.

Any ideas on how to encourage more participation in chatrooms for UXSE?

Comment: Given that you posted this question over a week ago, and I'm just the 16th viewer, I think the first question is: *"Any ideas on how to encourage more people to actually look at Meta?"* :)

Comment: Possible food for thought; ask other users what they want from UXSE and together push forward toward a shared goal. Become an extrovert who <s>pesters</s> talks with everyone and anyone, but not too much that it looks pushy for the other user(s). Allow 'off-topic' discussion and just generally banter with people. <s>Learn cult creation and integration skills.</s> I'd say the first problem is probably finding a couple of users to be the backbone of your chat.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I would be surprised if this question hasn't been asked before. I will have to look into it in more detail :p

Comment: @user137266 know anyone else interested? :)

Comment: I don't use chat because it is permanent and searchable. The word 'chat' should represent something ephemeral and limited. A better name for the SE version might be CareerLimitingMove. I avoid commenting on Qs and As because the whole thing can get "moved to chat", so the long shadow has a chilling effect on my participation.

Answer (score 1):

The only place I see the chat function is this tiny link in a menu I rarely access:

[image: Tiny chat link under speech balloon menu]

If there's a way to add it to the left nav, that would boost its discoverability.

I suspect a lot of people who don't have an official UXSE question would love to use it.

Comment: +1 I definitely agree with this, although I can understand that it detracts from the main purpose of UXSE.

Comment: It seems that there’s a missed opportunity to build a community here. I would love to meet the other people who I see every day on this site.